# Testing Facebook Messenger Scan Code

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-messenger

Facebook recently announced the introduction of [messenger codes](http://www.theverge.com/2016/4/7/11383958/facebook-messenger-codes-announced-900m-mau) which can be used to add new contacts and, more importantly, communicate directly with businesses and business pages (which is why I'm interested in it).

It took me ages to find it but on the bottom left of the messages tab on my Facebook page I have the option to download my code in three different sizes - clicking the disc will open a modal window where you can click the Download button and choose from 300, 600 or 1000px PNG file downloads.

[image]

NOTE: While they are PNG files the background is not transparent which seems like a bit of an oversight to me but hey ho that's what Photoshop is for I guess.

The problem is that while I can download my code I can't find any way to test it on printed materials (or even electronically at the moment!). The scanning feature doesn't seem to have been rolled out for me yet (I tried re-installing the Messenger app to see if I got a newer version but that didn't work) and nor for anyone I know (I'm in the UK). The codes are bespoke to Messenger so can't be scanned or tested using any other app.

I'm probably too far ahead of the game but is there any way I can test to see if my code scans correctly, or anywhere I can go to find out? I would like to use it on some promotional material which is likely to be long term materials that I don't want to have to update in the near future (several years, by which time it's likely these codes will be more commonplace).

I also need to know what the redundancy is like. For example the high redundancy QR codes I generate can have up to 30% of the code covered while still being usable, which is great for design purposes. I can't find any official documentation as yet for these codes at all, let alone what is required, what the spec. is etc.

I know the most likely option is 'sit and wait' but I really would rather not if possible. I've never been very patient...

Thanks

**UPDATE:** My Messenger app has now been updated so I can test, but I'm leaving this here in case anyone knows of another way to test perhaps? If someone doesn't have Messenger on their phone for example.

Comment: I've got the same problem, got my bot set up and want to test it.. Did you find a way to start chatting with it, without having to scan the code in the mobile app?

Comment: @ArEsiiX Nope not found anything yet I'm afraid!

Comment: @ArEsiiX My phone has now updated so I can scan the code!

Comment: From my initial testing, it doesn't seem like the code will work on a background other than white (or maybe some other light color).  I saved a copy of my code with a transparent background so I could use it on my business card design which has a black background.  Then I filled the transparent sections with black and tried to scan, but it wouldn't read the code.  Since you mentioned that you might Photoshop it for a transparent background, I was wondering if you happened to get it to work that way.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat I did Photoshop it to remove the background and changed the colour of the code to different colours, but all the testing I did was on a white background in the end as that was what the design needed. From what I recall it does require a high contrast and no 'noise' in the background, so a light solid colour would probably work but other than that I'm not too sure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried to replace the FB blue with white and put that on a black background to increase the contrast, but the Messenger app still wouldn't pick it up.  Looks like we're stuck with the blue-on-white for now.  Maybe "Z" will lift some of those restrictions one of these days.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat I got it to work with black on white so it's weird that it wouldn't work with white on black, but it's still in it's infancy really so hopefully it will get better.